# Errno::EACCES Permission denied @ sys_fail2 only on Windows Enviornment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app that takes in a CSV file then runs the data against the Barby barcode generator gem and creates Barcode PDFs then zips the file and sends the zip to the browser for download. It works totally fine on my mac book pro but when I pushed the project to my windows server I am getting an permission error even though I have full control on both the project folder and directory that ruby is installed to.

error message:

Errno::EACCES in ToolsController#barcode
Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (C:/rugbelt2/dump/barcodes.zip20161130-62088-1bsvaxl20161130-62088-63ne7b, C:/rugbelt2/dump/barcodes.zip20161130-62088-1bsvaxl)

Extracted source (around line #157):

```
  Zip::File.open(temp_file.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
```

controller code:

```
def barcode
    @input_filenames = []
    readQuad(params[:file])
    @array_of_hashes.length.times do | i |

      @sku = @array_of_hashes[i]['sku']
      puts @sku
      barcode = Barby::Code128.new(@sku)

      pdf = PDF::Writer.new(:paper => [10, 10])
      pdf.select_font "Times-Roman"
      barcode.annotate_pdf(pdf, :x => 40, :y => 125, :width => 1)
      pdf.trim_box(0, 0, 21, 29.7)
      pdf.text "SKU: " + @array_of_hashes[i]['sku'], :font_size => 12, :justification => :center
      pdf.text "STYLE: " + @array_of_hashes[i]['style'], :font_size => 12, :justification => :center
      pdf.text "ORIGIN: " + @array_of_hashes[i]['origin'], :font_size => 12, :justification => :center


      pdf.save_as("./dump/" + @array_of_hashes[i]['sku'] + '.pdf')
      @filename = @array_of_hashes[i]['sku'] + '.pdf'
      @input_filenames.push(@filename)

    end


    folder = "./dump/"
    filename = "barcodes.zip"
    temp_file = Tempfile.new(filename, "./dump/")

    begin

      Zip::OutputStream.open(temp_file) { |zos| }


      Zip::File.open(temp_file.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
        @input_filenames.each do |filename|

          zip.add(filename, folder + filename)
          end
      end


      zip_data = File.read(temp_file.path)



      send_data(zip_data, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => filename)
    ensure

      temp_file.close
      temp_file.unlink
    end


  end
```